# Internal working of strings with null characters

Tags: python

I just tried replacing a character in a python string with a null ('') character. Some weird things are happening. Can someone please explain me why is all this happening?

```
>>> a = "SampleText"
>>> a
'SampleText'
>>> a.replace('a','\0')
'S\x00mpleText'
>>> len(a)
10
>>> a.replace('\0','a')
'SampleText'
>>> len(a)
10
>>> a.replace('a','')
'SmpleText'
>>> len(a)
10
>>> a.replace('','a')
'aSaaamapalaeaTaeaxata'
>>> len(a)
10
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question, rather than links to images

Comment: You're not asigning the new value to any variable and it keeps `SampleText` in var `a`

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function returns the new string and therefore you need to asign it to a variable again. if you write `a = a.replace('a','\0')` it'll work as you expect it.